# How do I edit / create a new batch script to setup a bulk download from a series of links?

Tags: batch-file

Background - I'm trying to bulk download some videos from a website. I have all the links and while I can manually open the .bat file and paste the link (and repeat), I was wondering if there is a way to automate this so I could perhaps paste the set of links I have and either have it download continuously (so finish one and move on to the next) or any other automated way?

Here is the current script in the .bat file --

```
@ echo off
call set /p link=paste the link:
rem call set folder="%~dp0\videos\\"
set folder=M:\\Voot
If Not Exist %folder% MD %folder%
rem call set /p quality=write quality (write low medium or high):
Set quality=high
call set livestreamer="%~dp0\tools\livestreamer\\"
call "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" voot.php "%%link%%" "%%folder%%" "%%livestreamer%%" "%%quality%%"
:end1
pause
:end
```

Here are three links from the site:

```
http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/yaminis-truth-is-revealed/393087
http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/sesha-cohorts-with-yamini/393813
http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/the-saviour/389235
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I was wondering if there is a way to automate this

The easiest way to automate this is to save the links in a file and then use `for /f` to process the links file.

Use the following batch file (links.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=M:\\Voot"
if not exist %folder% md %folder%
set quality=high
set livestreamer="%~dp0\tools\livestreamer\\"
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`type links.txt`) do (
  echo "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" voot.php "%%i" "%folder%" "%livestreamer%" "%quality%"
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- The links are read from a file in the same directory as the batch file, called `links.txt`
- Remove the final `echo` in the file when you are happy that the `php` command is run with the correct parameters.
- You only need to use `%%` with the `for` parameter, for example `%%folder%%` can be replaced with `%folder%`

Example usage:

```
F:\test>type links.txt
http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/yaminis-truth-is-revealed/393087
http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/sesha-cohorts-with-yamini/393813
http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/the-saviour/389235

F:\test>links
"F:\test\\tools\php5.4\php.exe" voot.php "http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/yaminis-truth-is-revealed/393087" "M:\\Voot" ""F:\test\\tools\livestreamer\\"" "high"
"F:\test\\tools\php5.4\php.exe" voot.php "http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/sesha-cohorts-with-yamini/393813" "M:\\Voot" ""F:\test\\tools\livestreamer\\"" "high"
"F:\test\\tools\php5.4\php.exe" voot.php "http://www.voot.com/shows/naagin/1/359115/the-saviour/389235" "M:\\Voot" ""F:\test\\tools\livestreamer\\"" "high"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [type](http://ss64.com/nt/type.html) - Display the contents of one or more text files.

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks for the help and the links

Comment: @Serenity_Life You're welcome.