# How do I edit / create a new batch script to setup a bulk download from a series of links (with script)

Tags: batch

A few weeks ago, I posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1067498/how-do-i-edit-create-a-new-batch-script-to-setup-a-bulk-download-from-a-series) and got a wonderful answer.

I tried to apply the same techniques used to the following set of code for another website, but failed. The command prompt window would open and close immediately. So I'm back again.

Code:

```
@echo off
call set /p link=paste the link:
call set last=%%link:~-1,1%% 
rem call set folder="%~dp0\videos\\"
set folder=M:\\LiveStreamer\LiveStreamer\L
If Not Exist %folder% MD %folder%
call set livestreamer="%~dp0\tools\livestreamer\\"
call "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%"
IF  %last% NEQ c GOTO:nocollection
call set /p id=enter the Id of the video (example write 1000021386):
call "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%" "%%id%%"
call set /p quality=write quality (example write 720p):
call "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%" "%%id%%" "%%quality%%" "%%folder%%" "%%livestreamer%%"
GOTO end1
:nocollection
rem call set /p quality=write quality (example write 720p):
Set quality=1080p
rem call set /p choice=play or download? (write p or d):
set choice=d
call "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%" "%%quality%%" "%%folder%%" "%%livestreamer%%" "%%choice%%"
:end1
pause
:end
```

Would appreciate any help.

==== 
EDIT 5/7/16 with updated code below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "folder=C:\\Hotstar\H"
if not exist %folder% md %folder%
set livestreamer="%~dp0\tools\livestreamer\\"
"%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%"
set /p id=enter the Id of the video (example write 1000021386):
"%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%" "%%id%%"
"%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%link%%" "%%id%%" "%%quality%%" "%%folder%%" "%%livestreamer%%"
Set quality=1080p
set choice=d
set last=%%link:~-1,1%% 
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`type links.txt`) do (
  echo "%~dp0\tools\php5.4\php.exe" hotstarlivestreamer.php "%%i" "%id%" "%link%" "%quality%" "%folder%" "%livestreamer%" "%choice%"
  )
endlocal
```

However, when doing this I get errors:

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\hotstarsportslivestreamer-master\hotstarlivestreamer.php on line 135

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\hotstarsportslivestreamer-master\hotstarlivestreamer.php on line 139

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\hotstarsportslivestreamer-master\hotstarlivestreamer.php on line 141

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\hotstarsportslivestreamer-master\hotstarlivestreamer.php on line 143
Available streams:
enter the Id of the video (example write 1000021386):
```

The php errors in question refer to these lines in respective order:

```
$contentInfo=$resultObj->{'contentInfo'};

$contentTitle = $contentInfo2->contentTitle; $contentTitle=str_replace(" ","-",$contentTitle);

$episodeTitle = $contentInfo2->episodeTitle; $episodeTitle=str_replace(" ","-",$episodeTitle);

$episodeNumber= $contentInfo2->episodeNumber; $episodeNumber="episode$episodeNumber";
```

I'm not sure how to automate the "ID" entering portion though. This is a typical URL:

http://www.hotstar.com/tv/bahu-humari-rajni-kant/7326/kuhus-birthday-party/1000093419

The ID is the last part of the URL - 1000093419; even if I enter the numbers manually, I get the below errors:

Undefined offset in both lines 191 and 200 of the php file which refer to (I have edited the file to point out the lines):

```
if(isset($argv[2])){
    **<line 191>** if(isset($argv[2]) AND ($argv[5]=='d')){


    echo "Starting livestreamer...\n\n";
    echo shell_exec("$argv[4]livestreamer  \"$m3u8\" \"$argv[2]\" -o \"$argv[3]$filename.ts\" &");
    echo "Done.\n";
    }
    else{ 
    echo "Starting livestreamer...\n\n";
    **<line 192>** echo shell_exec("$argv[4]livestreamer  \"$m3u8\" \"$argv[2]\"  &");
    echo "Done.\n";
    }
    }
    else{ echo "Available streams: $bitrate\n";
```

Comment: Why do you have [call](http://ss64.com/nt/call.html) everywhere? Remove them all. Hint: call doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: If you look again at my "wonderful answer" [How do I edit / create a new batch script to setup a bulk download from a series of links?](http://superuser.com/a/1067632) you will see that there are no `call`s in the answer ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill Edited all the calls out and played around with the script and tested things out. I updated the OP with the edited code and the respective errors I'm getting. I think I'm experiencing issues because of the "IF  %last% NEQ c GOTO:nocollection" in the first unedited code. I'm not sure how to handle that.

Comment: You need to ask on [so] for the php programming issues.

Comment: IF will only parse numbers when `NEQ` is used.  Use `If /i not "%last%"=="c" goto:nocollection`

Comment: What OS? 32 or 64-bit?

Comment: i don't see any use of delayed expansion.  Use `setlocal enableextensions`

Comment: set "folder=C:\\Hotstar\H" is wrong. `set "folder=C:\Hotstar\H"`

Comment: set livestreamer="%~dp0\tools\livestreamer\\" is wrong.

Comment: why do you vary between `"%%link%%"` and `"%link%"`

Comment: Edit your question.  Remove your original code.